# Reading JSON data presented by uClassify url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am a noob and I need help in a project.
This is the API URL provided by the uClassify site,
https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uclassify/sentiment/classify/?readKey=YOUR_READ_API_KEY_HERE&text=This+is+the+text+to+classify

the JSON data is displayed as {"negative":0.0778055,"positive":0.922195}

Can someone please suggest a code in javascript to read the JSON data and store in a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

refer the following:

```
$("#ddlButton").click(function () {

 $.getJSON("https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uclassify/sentiment/classify/", { readKey: YOUR_READ_API_KEY_HERE,text=This+is+the+text+to+classify},
           function (data) {

               $.each(data, function (Modal, itemData) {


                       document.getElementById("text1").text= itemData.negative,
                       document.getElementById("text2").text= itemData.positive

               });
           });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: on ddlButton click event make api call. the json object returned in item data is assigned into textbox text1 & text2

Comment: I know it's too much to ask but could you please provide the whole program i am very new to programming and unable to include it ...

Comment: @udaykiran no, because that's your job. Newness isn't an excuse for laziness